# Represent Number Line in iphone app

Tags: iphone

I am looking to display number line in my application [image: Shown in picture here]

How this can be done? I also want to control number like programatically

Comment: hi shrini ...can u plz give some more information...

Comment: @AAAAAAAAA I want to draw a number line like shown above, you can discard numbers mentoned in picture though, Say I want to draw number line with 10 slots, and in each slot I should able to draw some pictures (Ex: Goals, yellow cards, substitut info) etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use views with different sizes and background colours. Use #define -s for the fixed sizes.

You should have 3 functions:
one that draws the horizontal red/blue rects

```
-(UIView *) drawHorizontal:(CGRect)frame withColor:(UIColor)theColor;
```

one that draws vertical spacers and labels underneath. Iterate for whole line width.

```
-(UIView *) drawVertical:(CGPoint)centerPosition withLabel:(int)number;
```

Your number line should be stored as an NSArray of NSDictionaries containing the position (index) and length of the horizontal red/blue lines.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy standard component to do this. You will need to subclass UIView and override drawRect. Then you can use Core Graphics to draw the number line.